# MFRC522 Not working over SPI Interface

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3, spi, rfid

I am running *(on a Pi3)* an MFRRC522 reader - much like this one: [image: Image from http://raspmer.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/how-to-use-rfid-rc522-on-raspbian.html]
It has been working fine, but after I changed SD card, to increase capacity - whilst also doing a new Raspian install I haven't been able to get it to work. 
I have done the following:

- Add `device_tree_param=spi=on` and `dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708` to the config.txt
- Taken a look in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`, but it's empty in the latest versions of Raspian anyway
- Enabled the SPI interface in raspi-config
- Installed [SPI-Py](https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git) and [MFRC522-python](https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python.git)
- Checked it's wired as [here](http://raspmer.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/how-to-use-rfid-rc522-on-raspbian.html)

The issue is - running `dmesg | grep spi` doesn't return anything. Have Raspian Updates removed the default modules? How do I enable the spi modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue:

Run `sudo rpi-update`

Make sure you have enabled the interface for this board with `dtoverlay=spi0-hw-cs` and `dtparam=spi=on` in the `config.txt`

And that should solve the problem. See https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1547 for further details

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I have exactly the same problem -.-

Comment: See for more details https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1547

Answer (score 2):

I always use `dtparam=spi=on`.

Remove the dtoverlay line, it is not needed.

By default the new `spi-bcm2853` module should be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I have done the above - and `lsmod` contains `spi_bcm2835`, but `dmesg | grep spi` still returns nothing - should it return something like `[    5.408904] bcm2708_spi 20204000.spi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
[    5.659213] bcm2708_spi 20204000.spi: SPI Controller at 0x20204000 (irq 80)`?

Comment: @JBithell It's simplest just to see if /dev/spi* exists.  If it does the driver is loaded.  As you have pointed out there seems to be a problem with the new driver and your particular device.